# xamarin - Add property to have a opaque background on custom ActivityIndicator

Tags: xamarin, background, activity-indicator

I have a custom Activiti Indicator image, with custom renderer for each platform (iOS and Android). The common class is:

```
public class MySpin : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AnimateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Animate",
        returnType: typeof(bool),
        declaringType: typeof(MazSpinner),
        defaultValue: false);

    public bool Animate
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AnimateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimateProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

It allows present a  image as a loading when Animate property is set.
It is possible to set a transparent and opaque background that cover the content where MySpin is called?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is possible.

**Renderer：** you can get state of Animate in renderer, then to do which you want.

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var customImage = e.NewElement as MySpin;
    if (customImage.Animate == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("true");
        Control.Alpha = 0; //transparent 
    }
    else
    {
        Control.Alpha = 1;// opaque 
        Console.WriteLine("false");
    }
}
```